# how to specify upload file size limit in struts 2?

Tags: struts2

I am trying to increase the default file upload size from from 2MB to 10 MB. 
and made some change in my struts.xml file.and added

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
```

and

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">500000</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

to current configuration. but the the property object value is null!! and the upload is not successful. some one suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your JSP and java code?

Comment: There are a number of questions/answers that address this here already. Have you looked at: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html also I would have assumed the units to be bytes, I forget are they kb's? If it is bytes then with the above you would have said restrict batch file uploads to 1 MB and the maximum file size to 1/2 MB (well roughly).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your application server? For example, Tomcat has it's own file upload limit (by default 2MB).

In the server.xml file in Tomcat's conf folder you would have to add the maxPostSize attribute with the maximum file size (in bytes). For 10MB, that would be something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="10485760" />
```

I don't really know about the configuration for other app servers, but shouldn't be much different.