# How can I get file uploads with struts 2 working for large files?

Tags: java, tomcat, file-upload, struts2, gradle

I want to develop a web-application with a fileupload mechanism using `struts2` with `fileUpload` which behaves strange and I can't figure out why.

I configured the fileupload mechanism in the struts.xml:

```
<package name="com.actions" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
<action name="excelupload" class="com.actions.FileuploadAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">10000000</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
        <result name="success">/fileupload.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/fileupload.jsp</result>

    </action>
</package>
```

The corresponding JSP:

```
<s:form action="excelupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <s:file name="excelfile" label="file" />
    <s:submit name="upload" value="upload" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

The corresponding Action:

```
public class FileuploadAction extends ActionSupport{
    File excelfile;
    public File getExcelfile() {
    return excelfile;
}

public void setExcelfile(File excelfile) {
    this.excelfile = excelfile;
}
    public String execute(){
        System.out.println(excelfile.getName());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When I upload a small file everything works fine. But when I try to upload a file that is larger than 2 MB the application throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request
was rejected because its size (3244109) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
```

To fix this issue I tried to add a `struts-default.properties` with

```
struts.multipart.maxSize=20097152
```

to the root of my the app's class path.

That fixed the exception but now `excelfile` is always `null`, regardless how large the file is.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**: For deployment I use Tomcat
**EDIT**: Added missing getter and setter methods.

Comment: Check the maximum file upload size limit of the server you are using.

Comment: I already tried this with <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="13485760"> in the struts.xml

Comment: Do you have getters and setters for your `File excelFile`?

Comment: yes, auto constructed by eclipse.

Comment: would this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6992933/1085285

Comment: you may have to set the mime type of the file in your action.  Go through this link, hope it helps.   http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/file-upload.html

Comment: excelfileContentType, excelfileFileName Are you getting proper values?

Comment: excelfile is null. So I can't call any methods on it. Adding a contenttype didn't help.

Comment: As MohanaRao suggested, the filename and contentTypes values can be set by Struts2, are they being set? See the link supplied by vandey. Additionally there are full file upload examples here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by removing

```
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">10000000</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

from the `struts.xml`.